# postgres commands working in shell but not in python script

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to create a postgres database, using a dumpfile, from a python script.

Following is the code I tried:

```
cmd='cat dump.sql.gz | zcat - | PGPASSWORD=my_password psql -d voylla_solr -h localhost -p 5432 -U user_name'
args = shlex.split(cmd)
p=subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()
```

I also tried using a different command:

```
cat dump.sql | PGPASSWORD=my_password psql -d voylla_solr -h localhost -p 5432 -U user_name
```

**EDIT* :** I used the following command:

```
subprocess.Popen("zcat dump.sql.gz | PGPASSWORD=my_password psql -d voylla_solr -h localhost -p 5432 -U user_name", shell=True);
```

It works, but it does not stop after the creation of the database. How can I stop its execution after the database os created?

Both of these commands are working in command line, but not in the python script. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You could simply say:

```
subprocess.Popen("zcat dump.sql.gz | PGPASSWORD=my_password psql -d voylla_solr -h localhost -p 5432 -U user_name", shell=True);
```

(Also refer to [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).)

Comment: this works but the execution of the command does not stop after the database gets created!!
How to stop it after the creation of the database?

Comment: this works but the execution of the command does not stop after the database gets created!! How to stop it after the creation of the database?